# RedisInsight : "Something went wrong adding the database. Please try again"

Tags: redis, redisinsights

I am getting an error while trying to add a redis database to redisInsight . Any suggestions to solve would be really helpful . I have tried with other Redis GUI , but receives the same error in redis server .

```
=== REDIS BUG REPORT START ===
Redis version: 6.2.5
[20948] 13 Sep 13:39:39.307 # --- EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
[20948] 13 Sep 13:39:39.309 # --- STACK TRACE
redis-server.exe!((null):0)(0x1401B3370, 0x0014FF60, 0x1400FCEF0, 0x0014E3C0)
redis-server.exe!((null):0)(0x0014E3C0, 0x1400FCE01, 0x00000000, 0x00000080)
KERNELBASE.dll!UnhandledExceptionFilter((null):0)(0x0014E470, 0x7FF89935663C, 0x00000000, 0x0014E408)
ntdll.dll!memset((null):0)(0x7FF899382A24, 0x7FF899210000, 0x0014E470, 0x7FF899240E7B)
ntdll.dll!_C_specific_handler((null):0)(0x00000000, 0x0014E970, 0x0014F030, 0x00000000)
ntdll.dll!_chkstk((null):0)(0x00000000, 0x0014E970, 0x0014F030, 0x00000000)
ntdll.dll!RtlRaiseException((null):0)(0x7FE17B555CC0, 0x7FE17B555CC0, 0x7FE193850000, 0x7FE17B555CC0)
ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x00000000, 0x7FE191000000, 0x00000000, 0x0000000F)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x7FE193850000, 0x00003A6D, 0x140044FE0, 0x00000002)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x00003A6D, 0x1401D9A98, 0x7FE193850000, 0x1400097C5)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x7FE193850000, 0x00000000, 0x140044E20, 0x140045680)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x7FE182800580, 0x7FE193850000, 0x7FE1AA414005, 0x00000000)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x7FE193850000, 0x7FE193850000, 0x7FE182800580, 0x7FE193850000)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x00000144, 0x7FE100000000, 0x00000000, 0x7FE193850000)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x7FE182800580, 0x00000001, 0x00000001, 0x00000000)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x7FE18D800320, 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x7FE1874001E0)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x00000001, 0xFFFFFFFF00000013, 0x00000000, 0x186A000000000)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x000051D4, 0x1401ACC60, 0x00000005, 0x0014FA88)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x00451400, 0x00451400, 0x00466CF0, 0x00451400)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00451400, 0x00000000)
redis-server.exe!KiUserExceptionDispatcher((null):0)(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk((null):0)(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart((null):0)(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart((null):0)(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
[20948] 13 Sep 13:39:39.316 # --- INFO OUTPUT
```

Comment: Which redis binary are you using? Microsoft's? Other?

Comment: Hi Nitrin0 .Others . I downloaded redis from this link .https://github.com/zkteco-home/redis